# What EC2 instance types does EKS support?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks

Where can I see a list of the instance types supported by Elastic Kuberenetes Service? This will help me automated the selection of an instance type.

Or are all instance types supported? Is a different list supported for Managed Node Groups?

The EKS Console offers only a third of all possible EC2 types as a selection (image below--the only list that I can find). However, I have seen [statements](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/baxrtj/eks_which_instance_types_and_why/)  that in fact all instance types are supported.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most instance types are available for use in Amazon EKS. The supported instance types for the latest version of the [Amazon VPC CNI plugin for Kubernetes](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s) are [shown here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/blob/release-1.6/pkg/awsutils/vpc_ip_resource_limit.go). You may need to [update your CNI version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-upgrades.html) to take advantage of the latest supported instance types.

You can find more information about [launching self-managed Amazon EKS Linux worker nodes here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html#self-managed-nodes).

Comment: Thank you? Assuming updated versions, I will take that as a list of supported Instance Types. Is the list the same for    Managed Node Groups and self-managed?

Comment: I couldn't find any additional documentation regarding available instance types for managed node-groups. I would assume that these are the ones listed in the AWS Management Console (your screenshot).

Comment: OK, so our conclusion is that the list you linked is for  self-managed  and my screenshot is for managed nodegroups. I wish there was a more authoritative list than that, since I use eksctl to launch clusters!